# Laravel groupBy and raw queries

Tags: php, laravel

I have never really worked with groupBy or raw queries, especially for a long time. I am just wondering if the following is possible:

```
$payments = Payment::all();

$grouped = $payments->groupBy('date');

dd($grouped->toArray());
```

The above will give me the following output:

```
"2018-08-21" => array:1 [▶]
"2018-06-21" => array:1 [▶]
```

What I want to do, is grab the data like this:

```
"2018-08-21" => array:2 [▶]
```

So basically I want to turn the months into the current month, and then group the data by the day. In the above example, the date `21-06-2018` has changed to `21-08-2018` and it was grouped with the other date on the 21st.

So to simply put, I just want to group the results by the day of my date column, whilst ignoring the months and years. Is this possible with a (raw) query, or should I manipulate the data afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also have used something similar to what @elitepc answered, the reason your solution works is because you are using correctly the groupBy Collection function, this solution uses the groupBy Eloquent query builder function. Not to get confused with them, or you gonna have a bad time.

This should work:

```php
$payments = Payment::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DAY(date)'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try something like this but unsure why it didn't work for me. Will try your solution since it looks like a better solution than the one I found :)

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$payments = Payment::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()
        ->groupBy(function($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('d');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
You can try this.

```
$payments = Payment::->select(*, DB::raw('DAY(date) AS day'))->get();

$grouped = $payments->groupBy('day');

dd($grouped->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by like this if I remember correctly:

```
$grouped = $payments->groupBy(DB::raw('DAY(date)'));
```

That way only the day part of the date will be considered to be grouped.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me, not too sure why since it looks like it should work. But I googled again and now I found something which did work. Will post as an answer.

Comment: Of course it will not. groupBy exist on both Eloquent query Builder and as a Collection function. This solution is passing a DB object to sort a collection.